# How do I fix "The name 'page' does not exist in the current context"

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have something like this in my controller

```
public ViewResult Index(string sortOrder, string currentFilter, string searchString, int? page)
{
 //I have all my code here
}
```

Then I have this in my Global.asax.cs file

```
config.For<Areas.Admin.Controllers.UsersController>(x => x.Index("sortOrder","currentFilter", "searchString", page)
```

Comment: No idea what `config.For()` is but should `page` be `"page"` (quotes)?

Comment: I did but page is not a string so it wouldn't work that way.

Comment: For the other parameters, your passing the name of the parameter (not the value) so why are you trying to pass a value in the case of `page` (as I said, I have no idea what `config.For()` is or does) but if you want to pass a value then define it (`int page=1` or whatever) so you can pass it to the method.

Comment: I used int? page because I am using it for page sorting in the application.

Comment: You passing a variable named `page` but you haven't declared it so of course it does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

From the comments, it really looks like you just need to do this

```
config.For<Areas.Admin.Controllers.UsersController>(x => x.Index("sortOrder","currentFilter", "searchString", "page")
```

Give it a try, as `page` seems to be a field name you're trying to reference, not a *declared* variable value.